# Different rlike behavior in Spark 1.6 and Spark 2.2

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am applying some filters to a dataframe in Spark 1.6 and Spark 2.2 and I am getting a totally different behavior. The code I am executing is:

```scala
val df = Seq(
  (1, 2),
  (3, 4),
  (5, 6),
  (7, 8)
).toDF("col1", "col2")

val filter = "col1 rlike '[\\x00-\\x1F\\x7F]'"
df.filter(filter).count
// This gives me 0 in Spark 1.6 and 4 in Spark 2.2

val filter2 = "col1 rlike '[\\\\x00-\\\\x1F\\\\x7F]'"
df.filter(filter2).count
// This gives me 4 in Spark 1.6 and 0 in Spark 2.2
```

Just in case it is important, Spark 1.6 is being executed along with Scala 2.10.5 and Spark 2.2 with 2.11.8.

Any idea of why this may be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour changed with this bug fix https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17647